# Extracting information from the largest rectangle in an image using openCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, contour, rectangles

I use the following code to find find out the largest rectangle of a captured image from the android camera:

```
private static Mat findLargestRectangle(Mat original_image) {
        Mat imgSource = original_image;

        Bitmap bmpOriOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgSource.cols(), imgSource.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Utils.matToBitmap(imgSource, bmpOriOut);

        try {
            bmpOriOut.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mediaAppPhotos/original.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //convert the image to black and white, commenting this wont crash
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

        //convert the image to black and white does (8 bit), commenting this crashes
        Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 50, 50);

        //apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots, commenting this crashes
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 5);

        //find the contours
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        double maxArea = -1;
        int maxAreaIdx = -1;        MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        Mat largest_contour = contours.get(0);
        List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
            //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
            if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                //check if this contour is a square
                MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
                int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.05, true);
                if (approxCurve.total() == 4) {
                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    maxAreaIdx = idx;
                    largest_contours.add(temp_contour);
                    largest_contour = temp_contour;
                }
            }
        }
        MatOfPoint temp_largest = largest_contours.get(largest_contours.size()-1);
        largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        largest_contours.add(temp_largest);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
        Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);

        //create the new image here using the largest detected square

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Largest Contour: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bitmap bmpOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgSource.cols(), imgSource.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Utils.matToBitmap(imgSource, bmpOut);

        try {
            bmpOut.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mediaAppPhotos/bigrect.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imgSource;
    }
```

Largest rectangle from the image is successfully detected like this: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9308/nn4w.png

But my question is, how can I save the DETECTED LARGEST RECTANGLE as a bitmap (without black and white)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of drawing it on the `imgSource` matrix:

```
Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
```

Create an empty black/white `Mat` and draw on it. Something like this (**black** initial matrix):

```
emptyMat = Mat.zeros(imgSource.size(), imgSource.channels());
...
Imgproc.drawContours(emptyMat, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
```

Of course, you can use the `Mat` constructor for creating the initial background matrix you want.

Comment: I am trying it now, could you also tell how to save it as RGB image instead of black and white.

Comment: You have it already in your code. You can use `cvtColor` with `Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB`; Or in initialization, use 3 channels instead of `imgSource.channels()` which has 1.

Comment: The sample project that is available with openCV SDK named "OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection" identifies the area according to the color. But it is not possible to extract that area. Will you be able to direct me?

Comment: I can't remember that example exactly. Can you tell me how it "identifies" the area? If it works with the contour of the area, then it is already doing the extraction and the only work left to do is to draw the contour on an empty matrix as was stated above.

Comment: Please run the project available with openCV SDK named "OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection"...I have no experience to say how the area is detected. I only want that area detected to be extracted..Please help!

Comment: I shouldn't do everything for you. You should learn how to read codes and search what you don't understand. About the example, I took a look at the code and the main function for processing the blob is `mDetector.process(mRgba)` which in turn, stores the extracted contours in a `List<MatOfPoint>`. You can get it using `mDetector.getContours()` and then show it on your own matrix.

Comment: That part I understood. You mean this list can be used to extract the image surrounded by the border? Thank you!

Comment: Normally, each `MatofPoint` would contain the points of a contour (border of a blob).